# AttributeError at / 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'users'

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, attributeerror

I don't know why I am getting this error I am new to Django I researched a lot but I didn't find an answer please when giving me the answer explain as much as you can I want to learn but if you don't want to no problem
Thank you,
This is my Views.py

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from home.forms import HomeForm
from home.models import Post, Friend


class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home/home.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = HomeForm()
        posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created')
        users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)
        friend = Friend.objects.filter(current_user=request.user)
        friends = friend.users.all()

        args = {
            'form': form, 'posts': posts, 'users': users, 'friends': friends
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def post(self, request):
        form = HomeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()

            text = form.cleaned_data['post']
            form = HomeForm()
            return redirect('home:home')

        args = {'form': form, 'text': text}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

def change_friends(request, operation, pk):
    friend = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if operation == 'add':
        Friend.make_friend(request.user, friend)
    elif operation == 'remove':
        Friend.lose_friend(request.user, friend)
    return redirect('home:home')
```

This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Friend(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    current_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owner', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @classmethod
    def make_friend(cls, current_user, new_friend):
        friend, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            current_user=current_user
        )
        friend.users.add(new_friend)

    @classmethod
    def lose_friend(cls, current_user, new_friend):
        friend, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            current_user=current_user
        )
        friend.users.remove(new_friend)
```

Traceback 1

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47,
 in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in

_get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in v
iew
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in d
ispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\Desktop\Alone-Osama\home\views.py", line 17, in get
    friends = friend.users.all()
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'users'
```

this is my code if you see some cheap code excuse me :D

Traceback 2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\Desktop\Alone-Osama\home\views.py", line 25, in get
    return render(request, self.template_name, args)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 312, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 446, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /
Exception Value: Reverse for 'create' not found. 'create' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Comment: Replace `filter` with `get` in the line before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's this line:

```
friends = friend.users.all()
```

You've forgotten that your model classes start with an upper case letter :)

```
friends = Friend.users.all()
```

Should work ... Basically there is no model called `friend` and therefore it certainly has no `user` attribute!

Comment: thank you so much but now I am getting this error NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'create' not found. 'create' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: I will post the traceback above

Comment: This is a second, entirely different issue. I don't see anywhere you're even referring to `create` above ... Maybe your template? I suggest posting a new question for this second error - include your `urls.py`, and show anywhere in your template that may be linking to a `create` view. But your original error has been solved.